# Knockout adding row

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, html-table

I´m new at knockout and I am trying to make a table, when we click "Remover" it removes the line, but when I click "Adicionar" I can't add any row to the table. If someone could help me I appreciate it.

http://jsfiddle.net/ThvdF/

```
<html>
<head>
    <title> Inseminações </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id='cssmenu'>
<ul>
  <li><a href="inseminações.html">Inseminações</a>
  <li><a href="tratamentos.html">Tratamentos</a>
  <li><a href="analises.html">Análises Clínicas</a>
</ul>
</div>
<br>
<h1> Inseminações </h1>
<table>
    <thead><tr>
        <th>Data</th>
        <th>SIA Vaca</th>
        <th>SIA Touro</th>
        <th>Nome do Touro</th>
        <th>Documento</th>
        <th>Inseminador</th> 
        <th> </th>
    </tr></thead>
    <tr>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: dtabela">
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="text: Data"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: SIAV"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: SIAT"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: NomeT"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: Doc"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: Ins"></td>
        <td><button data-bind='click: $root.removeDados'>Remover</button></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
         <tbody>
        <tr>
        <td><input data-bind='value: Data'/></td>
        <td><input data-bind='value: SIAV'/></td>
        <td><input data-bind='value: SIAT'/></td>
        <td><input data-bind='value: NomeT'/></td>
        <td><input data-bind='value: Doc'/></td>
        <td><input data-bind='value: Ins'/></td>
        <td><button data-bind='click: $root.addDados'>Adicionar</button></td>

        </tr>
     </tbody>
    </table>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='knockout-3.0.0.js'></script>
  <script type='text/javascript'>
  function Dados(Data,SIAV,SIAT,NomeT,Doc,Ins) {
            this.Data = ko.observable(Data);
            this.SIAV = ko.observable(SIAV);
            this.SIAT = ko.observable(SIAT);
            this.NomeT = ko.observable(NomeT);
            this.Doc = ko.observable(Doc);
            this.Ins= ko.observable(Ins);
        }
        function DadosViewModel () 
        {
            var self= this
            this.dtabela=ko.observableArray([
                new Dados("30-01-13", 354, 564, "Touro 1", "Doc1", "Inseminador A"),
                new Dados("12-05-13", 785, 344, "Touro 3", "Doc5", "Inseminador B"),
            ]);
            this.removeDados=function(Dados) {
                self.dtabela.destroy(Dados);
            };
            this.addDados=function(Dados) {
                self.dtabela.push( new Dados);
            };
        };
        var vm= new DadosViewModel();
        ko.applyBindings(vm);
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Brackets after `new Dados`?

Comment: you are passing `Dados` into the function...I think you want to pass the row and create a `new Dados(col1, col2,...)`

Comment: @abc123 where do i put new Dados (col1, col2,...) ?

Comment: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html I don't have time this moment to write the demo...sorry coding something else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I got your sample working, you can see a demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/ThvdF/2/

I had to make the following amendments

1. You had no viewmodel property to represent the new item, I added one:

   ```
   function DadosViewModel () 
   {
       var self= this
       ....
       this.newDados = ko.observable( new Dados(); ) // Here
   ```
2. You had 2 `tbody` tags, I change one to a `tfoot` and used the `with` binding to bind the footer row to the `newDados` viewmodel property

   ```
   <tfoot data-bind="with: newDados">
   ```
3. When passing this instance to the `addDados` method, I recreated `newDados`

   ```
   function DadosViewModel ()
   {
         ...
         this.addDados=function(d) {                
           self.dtabela.push( d );
           self.newDados( new Dados() );
        }
   ```

Comment: @Vasco - See update - simplified quite a bit. No need for a `clear ` method, just re-create the empty `Dados` in the footer

Comment: @Vasco - You're very welcome (Im also learnng knockout so this answer helped me learn!)

Comment: I have a problem, when I remove a line, I can't add another, and if I add  empty lines and remove one of them they are all deleted.

Edit: Forget it, I already fixed that. :D

Comment: That problem does not exist in the jsfiddle example in this question. It sounds like your code has something different. Perhaps post another question?

Comment: Thank you. What if I want to add multiple rows using the same values I filled?